# Correct use of lately

Tags: adverbs

According to Cambridge dictionary

We don't use lately for single events that happened recently

> I had a strange experience lately. (***wrong***)

But in my grammar I found a sentence

> I had a letter from him lately. (***if my grammar book is right***)

(nothing else is given about this sentence it is just an example)

Comment: Define *recently*. (It's open to interpretation. I see no reason to say that the sentence is *wrong* when talking about something that happened yesterday—or even earlier the same day. Uncommon perhaps, but not wrong.)

Comment: That dictionary is right. Why do people here question people like Cambridge? And who knows who wrote your grammar book. The reason Cambridge says it is wrong is because recently, lately and a few others use the perfect perfect, not the simple past, in standard grammar.

Answer (score 0):

The example in your grammar book is not a good example of English.  It is not ungrammatical, but could be better phrased as "... recently". I would prefer to give more specific information, for example, "... last week"

Some good examples would be:

> I had a letter from him last week.
>
> I haven't had any letters from him lately.

Comment: But more usual in the negative eg *I haven't had a letter from him lately*.

Answer (score 0):

> I had a letter from him lately.

Cambridge is right.  “Lately” applies to a *vague range* of time.  You could say

“I have been getting letters from him lately.”

or

“I have not gotten a letter from him lately.”

or

“I have gotten many letters from him lately.”

or

“I have been getting three letters a week from him lately.”

but **not**

“I have gotten a letter from him lately.”

or even

“I have gotten three letters from him lately.”

Both of those imply a specific time or time-range, so “lately” is inapplicable.

(Incidentally, “have” cannot mean “receive” in American English.  If you say, “I had a letter from him”, an American would interpret that as you *possess* the letter, perhaps in your pocket or your desk-drawer.)